# How to use different feature matrices for sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier (with class inheritance)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, classification

I have a dataset where there a bunch of different types of data for each each sample and I'd like to use separate models for different data types and use them together in `sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier`.  However, `StackingClassifier` takes the same feature matrix and applies different algorithms to it, then sends the probabilities to the meta classifier.

**Is there a way to specify particular feature matrices (representing the same samples) that correspond with specific algorithms in the `StackingClassifier`?**

If not, how can you use class inheritance of a `StackingClassifier` to adapt to this type of functionality?

Below is a very quick and non-elegant example (e.g., for demonstration only not for practicality) of using 2 feature sets (i.e., sepal features and pedal features from iris) from the same samples (i.e., iris samples).  Each feature set uses a different algorithm and then the probabilities are used as input into the meta classifier.

Doing it this way is very tedious...

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Data
X_sepal = pd.DataFrame({'sepal_length': {'iris_0': 5.1,'iris_1': 4.9,'iris_2': 4.7,'iris_3': 4.6,'iris_4': 5.0,'iris_5': 5.4,'iris_6': 4.6,'iris_7': 5.0,'iris_8': 4.4,'iris_9': 4.9,'iris_10': 5.4,'iris_11': 4.8,'iris_12': 4.8,'iris_13': 4.3,'iris_14': 5.8,'iris_15': 5.7,'iris_16': 5.4,'iris_17': 5.1,'iris_18': 5.7,'iris_19': 5.1,'iris_20': 5.4,'iris_21': 5.1,'iris_22': 4.6,'iris_23': 5.1,'iris_24': 4.8,'iris_25': 5.0,'iris_26': 5.0,'iris_27': 5.2,'iris_28': 5.2,'iris_29': 4.7,'iris_30': 4.8,'iris_31': 5.4,'iris_32': 5.2,'iris_33': 5.5,'iris_34': 4.9,'iris_35': 5.0,'iris_36': 5.5,'iris_37': 4.9,'iris_38': 4.4,'iris_39': 5.1,'iris_40': 5.0,'iris_41': 4.5,'iris_42': 4.4,'iris_43': 5.0,'iris_44': 5.1,'iris_45': 4.8,'iris_46': 5.1,'iris_47': 4.6,'iris_48': 5.3,'iris_49': 5.0,'iris_50': 7.0,'iris_51': 6.4,'iris_52': 6.9,'iris_53': 5.5,'iris_54': 6.5,'iris_55': 5.7,'iris_56': 6.3,'iris_57': 4.9,'iris_58': 6.6,'iris_59': 5.2,'iris_60': 5.0,'iris_61': 5.9,'iris_62': 6.0,'iris_63': 6.1,'iris_64': 5.6,'iris_65': 6.7,'iris_66': 5.6,'iris_67': 5.8,'iris_68': 6.2,'iris_69': 5.6,'iris_70': 5.9,'iris_71': 6.1,'iris_72': 6.3,'iris_73': 6.1,'iris_74': 6.4,'iris_75': 6.6,'iris_76': 6.8,'iris_77': 6.7,'iris_78': 6.0,'iris_79': 5.7,'iris_80': 5.5,'iris_81': 5.5,'iris_82': 5.8,'iris_83': 6.0,'iris_84': 5.4,'iris_85': 6.0,'iris_86': 6.7,'iris_87': 6.3,'iris_88': 5.6,'iris_89': 5.5,'iris_90': 5.5,'iris_91': 6.1,'iris_92': 5.8,'iris_93': 5.0,'iris_94': 5.6,'iris_95': 5.7,'iris_96': 5.7,'iris_97': 6.2,'iris_98': 5.1,'iris_99': 5.7,'iris_100': 6.3,'iris_101': 5.8,'iris_102': 7.1,'iris_103': 6.3,'iris_104': 6.5,'iris_105': 7.6,'iris_106': 4.9,'iris_107': 7.3,'iris_108': 6.7,'iris_109': 7.2,'iris_110': 6.5,'iris_111': 6.4,'iris_112': 6.8,'iris_113': 5.7,'iris_114': 5.8,'iris_115': 6.4,'iris_116': 6.5,'iris_117': 7.7,'iris_118': 7.7,'iris_119': 6.0,'iris_120': 6.9,'iris_121': 5.6,'iris_122': 7.7,'iris_123': 6.3,'iris_124': 6.7,'iris_125': 7.2,'iris_126': 6.2,'iris_127': 6.1,'iris_128': 6.4,'iris_129': 7.2,'iris_130': 7.4,'iris_131': 7.9,'iris_132': 6.4,'iris_133': 6.3,'iris_134': 6.1,'iris_135': 7.7,'iris_136': 6.3,'iris_137': 6.4,'iris_138': 6.0,'iris_139': 6.9,'iris_140': 6.7,'iris_141': 6.9,'iris_142': 5.8,'iris_143': 6.8,'iris_144': 6.7,'iris_145': 6.7,'iris_146': 6.3,'iris_147': 6.5,'iris_148': 6.2,'iris_149': 5.9},'sepal_width': {'iris_0': 3.5,'iris_1': 3.0,'iris_2': 3.2,'iris_3': 3.1,'iris_4': 3.6,'iris_5': 3.9,'iris_6': 3.4,'iris_7': 3.4,'iris_8': 2.9,'iris_9': 3.1,'iris_10': 3.7,'iris_11': 3.4,'iris_12': 3.0,'iris_13': 3.0,'iris_14': 4.0,'iris_15': 4.4,'iris_16': 3.9,'iris_17': 3.5,'iris_18': 3.8,'iris_19': 3.8,'iris_20': 3.4,'iris_21': 3.7,'iris_22': 3.6,'iris_23': 3.3,'iris_24': 3.4,'iris_25': 3.0,'iris_26': 3.4,'iris_27': 3.5,'iris_28': 3.4,'iris_29': 3.2,'iris_30': 3.1,'iris_31': 3.4,'iris_32': 4.1,'iris_33': 4.2,'iris_34': 3.1,'iris_35': 3.2,'iris_36': 3.5,'iris_37': 3.6,'iris_38': 3.0,'iris_39': 3.4,'iris_40': 3.5,'iris_41': 2.3,'iris_42': 3.2,'iris_43': 3.5,'iris_44': 3.8,'iris_45': 3.0,'iris_46': 3.8,'iris_47': 3.2,'iris_48': 3.7,'iris_49': 3.3,'iris_50': 3.2,'iris_51': 3.2,'iris_52': 3.1,'iris_53': 2.3,'iris_54': 2.8,'iris_55': 2.8,'iris_56': 3.3,'iris_57': 2.4,'iris_58': 2.9,'iris_59': 2.7,'iris_60': 2.0,'iris_61': 3.0,'iris_62': 2.2,'iris_63': 2.9,'iris_64': 2.9,'iris_65': 3.1,'iris_66': 3.0,'iris_67': 2.7,'iris_68': 2.2,'iris_69': 2.5,'iris_70': 3.2,'iris_71': 2.8,'iris_72': 2.5,'iris_73': 2.8,'iris_74': 2.9,'iris_75': 3.0,'iris_76': 2.8,'iris_77': 3.0,'iris_78': 2.9,'iris_79': 2.6,'iris_80': 2.4,'iris_81': 2.4,'iris_82': 2.7,'iris_83': 2.7,'iris_84': 3.0,'iris_85': 3.4,'iris_86': 3.1,'iris_87': 2.3,'iris_88': 3.0,'iris_89': 2.5,'iris_90': 2.6,'iris_91': 3.0,'iris_92': 2.6,'iris_93': 2.3,'iris_94': 2.7,'iris_95': 3.0,'iris_96': 2.9,'iris_97': 2.9,'iris_98': 2.5,'iris_99': 2.8,'iris_100': 3.3,'iris_101': 2.7,'iris_102': 3.0,'iris_103': 2.9,'iris_104': 3.0,'iris_105': 3.0,'iris_106': 2.5,'iris_107': 2.9,'iris_108': 2.5,'iris_109': 3.6,'iris_110': 3.2,'iris_111': 2.7,'iris_112': 3.0,'iris_113': 2.5,'iris_114': 2.8,'iris_115': 3.2,'iris_116': 3.0,'iris_117': 3.8,'iris_118': 2.6,'iris_119': 2.2,'iris_120': 3.2,'iris_121': 2.8,'iris_122': 2.8,'iris_123': 2.7,'iris_124': 3.3,'iris_125': 3.2,'iris_126': 2.8,'iris_127': 3.0,'iris_128': 2.8,'iris_129': 3.0,'iris_130': 2.8,'iris_131': 3.8,'iris_132': 2.8,'iris_133': 2.8,'iris_134': 2.6,'iris_135': 3.0,'iris_136': 3.4,'iris_137': 3.1,'iris_138': 3.0,'iris_139': 3.1,'iris_140': 3.1,'iris_141': 3.1,'iris_142': 2.7,'iris_143': 3.2,'iris_144': 3.3,'iris_145': 3.0,'iris_146': 2.5,'iris_147': 3.0,'iris_148': 3.4,'iris_149': 3.0}})
X_petal = pd.DataFrame({'petal_length': {'iris_0': 1.4,'iris_1': 1.4,'iris_2': 1.3,'iris_3': 1.5,'iris_4': 1.4,'iris_5': 1.7,'iris_6': 1.4,'iris_7': 1.5,'iris_8': 1.4,'iris_9': 1.5,'iris_10': 1.5,'iris_11': 1.6,'iris_12': 1.4,'iris_13': 1.1,'iris_14': 1.2,'iris_15': 1.5,'iris_16': 1.3,'iris_17': 1.4,'iris_18': 1.7,'iris_19': 1.5,'iris_20': 1.7,'iris_21': 1.5,'iris_22': 1.0,'iris_23': 1.7,'iris_24': 1.9,'iris_25': 1.6,'iris_26': 1.6,'iris_27': 1.5,'iris_28': 1.4,'iris_29': 1.6,'iris_30': 1.6,'iris_31': 1.5,'iris_32': 1.5,'iris_33': 1.4,'iris_34': 1.5,'iris_35': 1.2,'iris_36': 1.3,'iris_37': 1.4,'iris_38': 1.3,'iris_39': 1.5,'iris_40': 1.3,'iris_41': 1.3,'iris_42': 1.3,'iris_43': 1.6,'iris_44': 1.9,'iris_45': 1.4,'iris_46': 1.6,'iris_47': 1.4,'iris_48': 1.5,'iris_49': 1.4,'iris_50': 4.7,'iris_51': 4.5,'iris_52': 4.9,'iris_53': 4.0,'iris_54': 4.6,'iris_55': 4.5,'iris_56': 4.7,'iris_57': 3.3,'iris_58': 4.6,'iris_59': 3.9,'iris_60': 3.5,'iris_61': 4.2,'iris_62': 4.0,'iris_63': 4.7,'iris_64': 3.6,'iris_65': 4.4,'iris_66': 4.5,'iris_67': 4.1,'iris_68': 4.5,'iris_69': 3.9,'iris_70': 4.8,'iris_71': 4.0,'iris_72': 4.9,'iris_73': 4.7,'iris_74': 4.3,'iris_75': 4.4,'iris_76': 4.8,'iris_77': 5.0,'iris_78': 4.5,'iris_79': 3.5,'iris_80': 3.8,'iris_81': 3.7,'iris_82': 3.9,'iris_83': 5.1,'iris_84': 4.5,'iris_85': 4.5,'iris_86': 4.7,'iris_87': 4.4,'iris_88': 4.1,'iris_89': 4.0,'iris_90': 4.4,'iris_91': 4.6,'iris_92': 4.0,'iris_93': 3.3,'iris_94': 4.2,'iris_95': 4.2,'iris_96': 4.2,'iris_97': 4.3,'iris_98': 3.0,'iris_99': 4.1,'iris_100': 6.0,'iris_101': 5.1,'iris_102': 5.9,'iris_103': 5.6,'iris_104': 5.8,'iris_105': 6.6,'iris_106': 4.5,'iris_107': 6.3,'iris_108': 5.8,'iris_109': 6.1,'iris_110': 5.1,'iris_111': 5.3,'iris_112': 5.5,'iris_113': 5.0,'iris_114': 5.1,'iris_115': 5.3,'iris_116': 5.5,'iris_117': 6.7,'iris_118': 6.9,'iris_119': 5.0,'iris_120': 5.7,'iris_121': 4.9,'iris_122': 6.7,'iris_123': 4.9,'iris_124': 5.7,'iris_125': 6.0,'iris_126': 4.8,'iris_127': 4.9,'iris_128': 5.6,'iris_129': 5.8,'iris_130': 6.1,'iris_131': 6.4,'iris_132': 5.6,'iris_133': 5.1,'iris_134': 5.6,'iris_135': 6.1,'iris_136': 5.6,'iris_137': 5.5,'iris_138': 4.8,'iris_139': 5.4,'iris_140': 5.6,'iris_141': 5.1,'iris_142': 5.1,'iris_143': 5.9,'iris_144': 5.7,'iris_145': 5.2,'iris_146': 5.0,'iris_147': 5.2,'iris_148': 5.4,'iris_149': 5.1},'petal_width': {'iris_0': 0.2,'iris_1': 0.2,'iris_2': 0.2,'iris_3': 0.2,'iris_4': 0.2,'iris_5': 0.4,'iris_6': 0.3,'iris_7': 0.2,'iris_8': 0.2,'iris_9': 0.1,'iris_10': 0.2,'iris_11': 0.2,'iris_12': 0.1,'iris_13': 0.1,'iris_14': 0.2,'iris_15': 0.4,'iris_16': 0.4,'iris_17': 0.3,'iris_18': 0.3,'iris_19': 0.3,'iris_20': 0.2,'iris_21': 0.4,'iris_22': 0.2,'iris_23': 0.5,'iris_24': 0.2,'iris_25': 0.2,'iris_26': 0.4,'iris_27': 0.2,'iris_28': 0.2,'iris_29': 0.2,'iris_30': 0.2,'iris_31': 0.4,'iris_32': 0.1,'iris_33': 0.2,'iris_34': 0.2,'iris_35': 0.2,'iris_36': 0.2,'iris_37': 0.1,'iris_38': 0.2,'iris_39': 0.2,'iris_40': 0.3,'iris_41': 0.3,'iris_42': 0.2,'iris_43': 0.6,'iris_44': 0.4,'iris_45': 0.3,'iris_46': 0.2,'iris_47': 0.2,'iris_48': 0.2,'iris_49': 0.2,'iris_50': 1.4,'iris_51': 1.5,'iris_52': 1.5,'iris_53': 1.3,'iris_54': 1.5,'iris_55': 1.3,'iris_56': 1.6,'iris_57': 1.0,'iris_58': 1.3,'iris_59': 1.4,'iris_60': 1.0,'iris_61': 1.5,'iris_62': 1.0,'iris_63': 1.4,'iris_64': 1.3,'iris_65': 1.4,'iris_66': 1.5,'iris_67': 1.0,'iris_68': 1.5,'iris_69': 1.1,'iris_70': 1.8,'iris_71': 1.3,'iris_72': 1.5,'iris_73': 1.2,'iris_74': 1.3,'iris_75': 1.4,'iris_76': 1.4,'iris_77': 1.7,'iris_78': 1.5,'iris_79': 1.0,'iris_80': 1.1,'iris_81': 1.0,'iris_82': 1.2,'iris_83': 1.6,'iris_84': 1.5,'iris_85': 1.6,'iris_86': 1.5,'iris_87': 1.3,'iris_88': 1.3,'iris_89': 1.3,'iris_90': 1.2,'iris_91': 1.4,'iris_92': 1.2,'iris_93': 1.0,'iris_94': 1.3,'iris_95': 1.2,'iris_96': 1.3,'iris_97': 1.3,'iris_98': 1.1,'iris_99': 1.3,'iris_100': 2.5,'iris_101': 1.9,'iris_102': 2.1,'iris_103': 1.8,'iris_104': 2.2,'iris_105': 2.1,'iris_106': 1.7,'iris_107': 1.8,'iris_108': 1.8,'iris_109': 2.5,'iris_110': 2.0,'iris_111': 1.9,'iris_112': 2.1,'iris_113': 2.0,'iris_114': 2.4,'iris_115': 2.3,'iris_116': 1.8,'iris_117': 2.2,'iris_118': 2.3,'iris_119': 1.5,'iris_120': 2.3,'iris_121': 2.0,'iris_122': 2.0,'iris_123': 1.8,'iris_124': 2.1,'iris_125': 1.8,'iris_126': 1.8,'iris_127': 1.8,'iris_128': 2.1,'iris_129': 1.6,'iris_130': 1.9,'iris_131': 2.0,'iris_132': 2.2,'iris_133': 1.5,'iris_134': 1.4,'iris_135': 2.3,'iris_136': 2.4,'iris_137': 1.8,'iris_138': 1.8,'iris_139': 2.1,'iris_140': 2.4,'iris_141': 2.3,'iris_142': 1.9,'iris_143': 2.3,'iris_144': 2.5,'iris_145': 2.3,'iris_146': 1.9,'iris_147': 2.0,'iris_148': 2.3,'iris_149': 1.8}})
y_iris = pd.Series({'iris_0': 'setosa','iris_1': 'setosa','iris_2': 'setosa','iris_3': 'setosa','iris_4': 'setosa','iris_5': 'setosa','iris_6': 'setosa','iris_7': 'setosa','iris_8': 'setosa','iris_9': 'setosa','iris_10': 'setosa','iris_11': 'setosa','iris_12': 'setosa','iris_13': 'setosa','iris_14': 'setosa','iris_15': 'setosa','iris_16': 'setosa','iris_17': 'setosa','iris_18': 'setosa','iris_19': 'setosa','iris_20': 'setosa','iris_21': 'setosa','iris_22': 'setosa','iris_23': 'setosa','iris_24': 'setosa','iris_25': 'setosa','iris_26': 'setosa','iris_27': 'setosa','iris_28': 'setosa','iris_29': 'setosa','iris_30': 'setosa','iris_31': 'setosa','iris_32': 'setosa','iris_33': 'setosa','iris_34': 'setosa','iris_35': 'setosa','iris_36': 'setosa','iris_37': 'setosa','iris_38': 'setosa','iris_39': 'setosa','iris_40': 'setosa','iris_41': 'setosa','iris_42': 'setosa','iris_43': 'setosa','iris_44': 'setosa','iris_45': 'setosa','iris_46': 'setosa','iris_47': 'setosa','iris_48': 'setosa','iris_49': 'setosa','iris_50': 'versicolor','iris_51': 'versicolor','iris_52': 'versicolor','iris_53': 'versicolor','iris_54': 'versicolor','iris_55': 'versicolor','iris_56': 'versicolor','iris_57': 'versicolor','iris_58': 'versicolor','iris_59': 'versicolor','iris_60': 'versicolor','iris_61': 'versicolor','iris_62': 'versicolor','iris_63': 'versicolor','iris_64': 'versicolor','iris_65': 'versicolor','iris_66': 'versicolor','iris_67': 'versicolor','iris_68': 'versicolor','iris_69': 'versicolor','iris_70': 'versicolor','iris_71': 'versicolor','iris_72': 'versicolor','iris_73': 'versicolor','iris_74': 'versicolor','iris_75': 'versicolor','iris_76': 'versicolor','iris_77': 'versicolor','iris_78': 'versicolor','iris_79': 'versicolor','iris_80': 'versicolor','iris_81': 'versicolor','iris_82': 'versicolor','iris_83': 'versicolor','iris_84': 'versicolor','iris_85': 'versicolor','iris_86': 'versicolor','iris_87': 'versicolor','iris_88': 'versicolor','iris_89': 'versicolor','iris_90': 'versicolor','iris_91': 'versicolor','iris_92': 'versicolor','iris_93': 'versicolor','iris_94': 'versicolor','iris_95': 'versicolor','iris_96': 'versicolor','iris_97': 'versicolor','iris_98': 'versicolor','iris_99': 'versicolor','iris_100': 'virginica','iris_101': 'virginica','iris_102': 'virginica','iris_103': 'virginica','iris_104': 'virginica','iris_105': 'virginica','iris_106': 'virginica','iris_107': 'virginica','iris_108': 'virginica','iris_109': 'virginica','iris_110': 'virginica','iris_111': 'virginica','iris_112': 'virginica','iris_113': 'virginica','iris_114': 'virginica','iris_115': 'virginica','iris_116': 'virginica','iris_117': 'virginica','iris_118': 'virginica','iris_119': 'virginica','iris_120': 'virginica','iris_121': 'virginica','iris_122': 'virginica','iris_123': 'virginica','iris_124': 'virginica','iris_125': 'virginica','iris_126': 'virginica','iris_127': 'virginica','iris_128': 'virginica','iris_129': 'virginica','iris_130': 'virginica','iris_131': 'virginica','iris_132': 'virginica','iris_133': 'virginica','iris_134': 'virginica','iris_135': 'virginica','iris_136': 'virginica','iris_137': 'virginica','iris_138': 'virginica','iris_139': 'virginica','iris_140': 'virginica','iris_141': 'virginica','iris_142': 'virginica','iris_143': 'virginica','iris_144': 'virginica','iris_145': 'virginica','iris_146': 'virginica','iris_147': 'virginica','iris_148': 'virginica','iris_149': 'virginica'})

# Training/Testing
idx_training, idx_testing = train_test_split(y_iris.index, stratify=y_iris, random_state=0)

# Classifiers
clf_sepal = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=LinearSVC(random_state=0), random_state=0, algorithm='SAMME')
clf_petal = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)
clf_meta = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)

# Fitting base classifiers
clf_sepal.fit(X_sepal.loc[idx_training], y_iris.loc[idx_training])
clf_petal.fit(X_sepal.loc[idx_training], y_iris.loc[idx_training])

# Fitting meta classifier
clf_meta.fit(
    X=pd.concat([
        pd.DataFrame(clf_sepal.predict_proba(X_sepal.loc[idx_training]), index=idx_training, columns=pd.Index(clf_sepal.classes_).map(lambda j: "sepal__{}".format(j))),
        pd.DataFrame(clf_petal.predict_proba(X_petal.loc[idx_training]), index=idx_training, columns=pd.Index(clf_petal.classes_).map(lambda j: "petal__{}".format(j))),
    ], axis=1),
    y=y_iris.loc[idx_training],
)

# Predicting with meta classifier
y_hat = pd.Series(
    clf_meta.predict(
        X=pd.concat([
            pd.DataFrame(clf_sepal.predict_proba(X_sepal.loc[idx_testing]), index=idx_testing, columns=pd.Index(clf_sepal.classes_).map(lambda j: "sepal__{}".format(j))),
            pd.DataFrame(clf_petal.predict_proba(X_petal.loc[idx_testing]), index=idx_testing, columns=pd.Index(clf_petal.classes_).map(lambda j: "petal__{}".format(j))),
        ], axis=1),
    ),
    index=idx_testing,
)

print("Accuracy on test set:", np.mean(y_hat == y_iris.loc[idx_testing]))
# Accuracy on test set: 0.9736842105263158
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the column selection as part of a pipeline for the base estimators.  One approach to that is a `ColumnTransformer`, which is a little verbose for the purpose but the alternatives I know about (`FunctionTransformer` e.g.) are a little less robust.

```py
sepal_cols = ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width']
petal_cols = ['petal_length', 'petal_width']

X = X_iris  # as loaded from sklearn, or the hstack of your examples

pipe_sepal = Pipeline([
    ('select', ColumnTransformer([('sel', 'passthrough', sepal_cols)], remainder='drop')),  # remainder='drop' is the default, but I've included it for clarity
    ('clf', clf_sepal)
])
pipe_petal = Pipeline([
    ('select', ColumnTransformer([('sel', 'passthrough', petal_cols)], remainder='drop')),
    ('clf', clf_petal)
])

stack = StackingClassifier(
    estimators=[
        ('sepal', pipe_sepal),
        ('petal', pipe_petal),
    ],
    final_estimator=clf_meta,
    ...
)

stack.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_hat = stack.predict(X_test)
```

---

Your manual method, in addition to being tedious, is statistically unsound: your base models are making predictions *on their own training set* to be used as inputs to the meta-estimator.  This can generally lead to the meta-estimator giving preference to the most-overfit base estimator; I assume your high testing score (which does appear to be valid) is just due to iris being relatively easy?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. I thought that's what the StackingClassifier does? It uses the probabilities from the base models, stacks them column wise, then uses that as input into the meta classifier. Above, to be clear, is using a specific feature set *only* for each classifier correct?

Comment: To the main point, yes.  The two base estimators of the stack get the full dataset, but then inside those pipelines we drop all the non-passthrough columns, so the actual classifiers only see the subsets.  You should be able to inspect the `n_features_in_` attribute to check.

Comment: To the secondary point, your description is correct, but the "probabilities from the base models" used to train the meta-estimator are generated by cross-validation to avoid the data leakage I described.  So each prediction is made by a classifier trained _not_including the prediction row.