# Multiouput stacked regression with a single final estimator

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, multipleoutputs

Is there a way to train a stacked regressor with scikit-learn such that a single final estimator is used to return multiple outputs?

I have been using [`sklearn.ensemble.StackingRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.StackingRegressor.html) but, as indicated in the documentation of the `.fit()` method, this is only suitable if the final estimator returns an output of shape *(n_samples,)* while I would need *(n_samples, n_features)*.

As a workaround, Sklearn implements [`sklearn.ensemble.MultiOutputRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html) (as proposed here: [Multioutput Stacking Regressor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60378363/multioutput-stacking-regressor)) which extends monovariate models into multivariate ones by training a separate model for each output feature. I got this solution to run, however, I am not satisfied with this as it takes too long to train on high-dimensional data and needlessly multiplies the number of parameters.

Instead, I would like to use a single final estimator (*e.g.* a random forest) that can take a multivariate input and return a multivariate output. This would make the prediction pipeline straightforward and, I believe, faster to train.

The following illustration represents what I would like to achieve:

```
+-----------------------+----+--------------+-------------------------------------------+----+-------------+----+------------------+
| Set of observations 1 | -> | Base Model 1 |                                           |    |             |    |                  |
|    (nsmpls, nfeats)   |    |              |                                           |    |             |    |                  |
+-----------------------+----+--------------+-------------------------------------------+----+-------------+----+------------------+
|                                           | Concatenated predictions from base models | -> | Final model | -> | Final prediction |
|                                           |             (nsmpls, 2 * nfeats)          |    |             |    | (nsmpls, nfeats) |
+-----------------------+----+--------------+-------------------------------------------+----+-------------+----+------------------+
| Set of observations 2 | -> | Base Model 2 |                                           |    |             |    |                  |
|    (nsmpls, nfeats)   |    |              |                                           |    |             |    |                  |
+-----------------------+----+--------------+-------------------------------------------+----+-------------+----+------------------+
```

In this specific example the number of input and output features are identical for the base models, but the rational would be the same in a different setup. Also, the set of input features are different for each base model, but this is a separate issues that I solved using: [How to use different feature matrices for sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier (with class inheritance)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70596576/how-to-use-different-feature-matrices-for-sklearn-ensemble-stackingclassifier-w)

I could also directly train the final model on the concatenated inputs (as opposed to the concatenated predictions) without stacking, but I would also like to have these 2 base models trained as they are of interest on their own. The pipeline I described here would kill two birds with one stone.

Comment: The documentation for `StackingRegressor.predict` indicates it can produce output of shape `(n_samples, n_output)`; what happens if you just try a random forest as final estimator?

Comment: @BenReiniger There is actually a strange inconsistency in the docs of `StackingRegressor` as `.predict` indicates that multioutput is possible while `.fit` indicates it is not.

Trying to fit a stack with a random forest as final estimator returns the following error:
`ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (XXX, YYY) instead.` Where `XXX` is the number of observations and `YYY` is the number of predicted features.

Comment: To follow-up on this, I just found this GitHub issue which is identical to my problem. They do highlight that the current documentation is incorrect.